# When APNS tokens fail, is it a must to repeat the remaining push notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pyapns

I'm sending 1-10 notifications at a time, sometimes one of the tokens fail, I'm guessing they fail when a user deletes the app (or other similar reasons), do I need to retry the remaining tokens/notifications for that batch? (I receive a "failed token" warning later on from PyAPNS)

The tokens are all valid tokens, it's stated that malformed tokens require a retry of the remaining push notifications, however I'm wondering whether I need to retry too with non-malformed tokens, it would be pretty stupid If I need to retry in the above scenario, people delete apps all the time, I'm guessing a high percentage of batches would require a retry

(There are many questions related to this issue, however I wasn't able to find a definite answer, from my trials I'm guessing I already have my answer, It seems the notifications aren't delivered in the above scenario)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what causes PyAPNS to return a "failed token" warning. If it refers to a token belonging to a device that uninstalled the app (which I doubt, since such device tokens are only returned by the Feedback Service), you don't have to re-send the remaining notifications.

However, if this failure is caused by an error response of InvalidToken, this means the connection to APNS was closed after the invalid token was processed, and any notifications that were sent after it must be re-sent.

Comment: The response is from the feedback server

Comment: @KaanSoral In that case, you don't have to re-send anything.